# Multiple v-for for multiple arrays of objects - using the same index

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have two different props being passed to my component. The props are arrays of objects. While this data isn't the same in this arrays, the data in 0 index from one array, is relevant to the 0 in the other array.

[image: one array]

The data you can see here (at index 0) in my generalGame prop is relevant to the data you will find in my specificGame prop, also at the index of 0

[image: two array]

As you can see the gameId is the same, but I get further information.

Currently i have :

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(games, index) in generalGame" v-bind:key="generalGame" class="card">

        <img :src="getChampImage(specificGame[index].champion)">
         // This specificGame is the first image shown


         <p> {{ games.participantIdentities[index].player.summonerName }}</p>

     </li>
</ul>

My Props are 

 props: ['generalGame', 'specificGame'],
```

This outputs the champion from the first picture and only one of the players located in participantIdentities from the second picture.

How can i get all the data from the participantIdentities while staying on the same index?

Comment: Ideally you'd restructure your data so that `generalGame` and `specificGame` are in the same array rather than relying on two arrays being the same length. It's not possible to say what the best way to do that is from the code you've posted but you could, for example, have a computed property that creates an array of objects that have `generalGame` and `specificGame` properties so that the two game types are paired up in a single array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array, and each item of this array contains an array. In order to access all the elements of the nested arrays, you need to iterate during an iteration.

Let's say you have an array of 3 items and you want to iterate through it. it will look like this:

`iteration 1 -> iteration 2 -> iteration 3`

Now let's say each item has an array of 2 items and you want to iterate through all of these items. It will look like this:

```
i1           -> i2           -> i3
i1.1 -> i1.2    i2.1 -> i2.2    i3.1 -> i3.2
```

Each time you iterate through an item, you make another loop, nested in the first one. During iteration i1, you do iteration i1.1 then i1.2.

In JS, this nested iteration would look like this:

```
for (let index1 = 0; index1 < 3; index1++) {
    for (let index2 = 0; index2 < 3; index2++) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

---

`games.participantIdentities[index]` is an iteration of the array `games.participantIdentities`, and `games` is an iteration of the array `generalGame`.

Accessing every `participantIndentity` would look like this:

```
<p
    v-for="(participantIdentity, participantIdentityIndex) in games.participantIdentities"
    v-bind:key="participantIdentityIndex"
>
    {{ participantIdentity.player.summonerName }}
</p>
```

Comment: I think you need to drop the `[index]` from the end of your `v-for`. It's also not entirely clear why you've included `v-bind="participantIdentity"`.

Comment: @skirtle thanks for pointing out these mistakes, I fixed them.

Comment: The new version binds the `key` to an object, which isn't valid.

Comment: @skirtle fixed, ty